# fb ios sdk 4.8 share image and url at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

How can i share a link and image at the same time to fb using the 4.x sdk? I've been trying everything I could find and I got nowhere. I believe you can do this if you redirect to the native app but I would prefer to do it internally in my app. Also it would be great if the image would show up on fb and if the user tapes it he is redirected to the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking you can't share a link and an image in the same post. What you can do is set the image you want to share as the `og:image` for the URL you are sharing in the markup of that URL.

A bit of background to the why: if you want to share both at the same time you would need to automatically append the URL to the user message when uploading the image, however, this would be considered pre-filling if the user does not type the URL on their own, character by character.